# Warp mesh to retain shape when changing focal length of camera

Tags: camera

Bascially, what I want to do is modify the mesh by warping it so that when the focal length of the camera changes, the mesh appears the same to the camera. I'm not sure if this feature is in blender, but if not, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Do you need to modify the mesh, or can you just use two scenes - one for the mesh object and a non-changing camera and one for the scene that changes focal length minus the mesh object?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the Vertigo Effect, or [Dolly Zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_zoom) however those are achieved through camera effects alone, not mesh warping

Comment: @CraigDJones I want the mesh object to change; it should distort and warp when the focal length of the camera changes so it appears exactly the same to the camera at a different focal length after changed.

Comment: I don't understand. When you change focal length (or FOV) the mesh does not distort, only visually scales. But moving the camera closer/further the subject changes the perspective (visually distorts the object). Can you elaborate what you want more precisely and your end goal is?